# Interleaving items with Rxjava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

Give two obserable streams {1,3} and {2,4} is there any operator that can produce a result of 
{1,2,3,4}

I thought merge was for this and went on doing

```
List<Integer> result=Observable.merge(Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1,3)),Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(2,4))).toList().blockingGet();
```

However I later found out that merge "can" interleave but it wont as long as sync operations are performed.

Any pointers?

Comment: Interleave how? In a round-robin fashion, taking an item from the first source, then one from the second, then another from the first, etc? Or do you want an ordered merged sequence by picking the next smallest item whichever source produces it?

Comment: Akarnokd the former i.e round robin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard operator for that. You can try and map items into tuples of (index, value) where index is 0, 2, 4, etc for the first source and 1, 3, 5 for the second. Then use [orderedMerge](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions/blob/e43c914f059667023ce465a40cac1f6082b73e08/src/main/java/hu/akarnokd/rxjava2/operators/Flowables.java#L103) to compare the indices of the tuples, then after the merge, extract the value.

Something like this:

```java
AtomicInteger index1 = new AtomicInteger();
Flowable<Pair<Integer, T>> indexedSource1 = source1
    .map(v -> new Pair<>(index1.getAndAdd(2), v));

AtomicInteger index2 = new AtomicInteger(1);
Flowable<Pair<Integer, T>> indexedSource2 = source2
    .map(v -> new Pair<>(index2.getAndAdd(2), v));

Flowables.orderedMerge(
    (a, b) -> a.first.compareTo(b.first), 
    indexedSource1, 
    indexedSource2
)
.map(v -> v.second);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one more way to do that . There is no obvious benefit that i can see from the above given solution . However it just uses a normal zip operator to achieve the result.

```
        List<Integer> intArray1 = Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7);
        List<Integer> intArray2 = Arrays.asList(2,4,6,8);
        Observable.zip(
                Observable.fromIterable(intArray1),
                Observable.fromIterable(intArray2),
                (numbers1, numbers2) -> new Pair<>(numbers1, numbers2)).
                collect(ArrayList<Integer>::new,
                        (list, pair) -> {
                            list.add(pair.first);
                            list.add(pair.second);
                        }).
                subscribe(mergedList -> {
                    Log.d("List", mergedList.size() + "");
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

If the sources are cold observables and if i need to combine the elements of the sources, I would use `zip` :

```
    Observable<Integer> stream1 = Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 3));
    Observable<Integer> stream2 = Observable.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(2, 4));

    List<Integer> integers = Observable.zip(stream1, stream2, (a, b) -> Observable.just(a, b))
            .flatMap(ob -> ob)
            .toList()
            .blockingGet();
```